# CREATE USER in Dynamic SQL for each database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to create a user for a login and assign some permission, and I want to do this for databases whose name is > 4 Here's what I have

```html
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'Declare @name varchar(100), @UserToAdd VARCHAR(100) = ''HQ\tname''
select @name = ''?''
PRINT @name
IF db_id(@name) > 4

BEGIN
USE ?
EXEC (''CREATE USER ['' + @UserToAdd + ''] FOR LOGIN ['' + @UserToAdd + ''];'')
EXEC (''EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', N'''' + @UserToAdd + '''';'')
END'
```

I'm having some trouble with the syntax using multiple quotes, If I just run this for an individual database I know it works using the following code

```html
DECLARE @UserToAdd VARCHAR(100) = 'HQ\tname'
BEGIN
USE [dbnamehere]
EXEC ('CREATE USER [' + @UserToAdd + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @UserToAdd + '];')
EXEC ('EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', N''' + @UserToAdd + ''';')
END
```

Could anyone help out with the syntax?

Comment: sometimes you need four quotes to get a quote in the sql to exec,  The quick way to see if you've got it right is to change exec to print, you'll see the sql it's trying to use then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with a cursor:

```
declare 
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @db sysname,
    @UserToAdd sysname = 'HQ\tname';

declare db_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
select
    name
from
    sys.databases
where
    database_id > 4;

open db_cursor;

fetch next from db_cursor into @db;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'use ' + quotename(@db) + ';
    create user ' + quotename(@UserToAdd) + ' for login ' + quotename(@UserToAdd) + ';
    exec sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ' + quotename(@UserToAdd, '''') + ';';
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
    fetch next from db_cursor into @db;        
end;

close db_cursor;
deallocate db_cursor;
```